# Davis' trick and Riemannian manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $C$ be a finite 2-dimensional aspherical complex. The Michael Davis' trick is basically the following:  One embeds $C$ to, say, ${\mathbb R}^5$, then takes a regular neighborhood in ${\mathbb R}^5$, producing a manifold $M$ with boundary. Then we triangulate the boundary and using a right angled Coxeter reflection group $G$ acting on ${\mathbb R}^5$, by gluing together all the images $GM'$, produce a manifold $M'$ on which $G$ acts properly by isometries. Factoring by a torsion-free finite index subgroup $H < G$, produce a closed aspherical manifold $M'/H$ whose fundamental group contains $\pi_1(C)$.

**Question.**  Can we get a closed smooth (Riemannian) aspherical manifold where $C$ $\pi_1$-embeds?

I think, by reading Davis' Annals paper published in 1983 that the answer is "yes", but I would like to make sure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes: you just have to make sure you model $M$ on a manifold with corners. Then the reflections should fit together to get a smooth manifold structure on M'. 

Comment: @Ian: Yes, that is what I thought too. But I need something to refer to. It is needed for my paper.

Comment: @Ian: Davis also writes that in dim 4 the situation is different.

Comment: @Mark: I think, the reference is Davis's book, Proposition 11.1.3 (iv). That's what the number is in my electronic (and posssibly preliminary) copy; it is in the chapter on reflection group trick.
The statement is that if the regular neighborhood and the triangulation of the boundary are smooth (which can always be arranged in your case) then the quotient aspherical manifold is  smooth.  

Comment: @Igor: I guess this is what I need then. I will just refer to Davis' book. I have asked Michael Davis himself of course, but I figured it may be faster to ask on MO, and I was right. 

Comment: Actually, the book is on his homepage: http://www.math.osu.edu/~mdavis/my%20book/My%20book.html

Comment: A slightly pedantic comment: the group $G$ in Mark's posting does not come equipped with an action on $\mathbb{R}^5$.  The manifold $M'$ with the proper $G$-action is constructed from $G\times M$, i.e., the direct product of $G$ and $M$, by identifying pieces of the various copies of $\partial M$.  Provided that the 2-complex $C$ that you started with was aspherical, the universal cover of $M'$ will be contractible.  But even in this case, it need not be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^5$.